# Every hyperbolic matrix $A\in SL(3,\mathbb{Z})$ has 3 distinct eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Let $A\in SL(3,\mathbb{Z})$ be a hyperbolic matrix (i.e., the absolute value of each eigenvalue is not $1$), then all its eigenvalues are real and different.

I read this result [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.2860), Proposition 4.12.
But I didn't see how to prove it.
Is there a simple proof?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Far from a complete answer, but a transformation of the issue of distinctness into a tractable condition.

The characteristic polynomial, using a Viete formula, is

$$P(z)=-z^3+az^2+bz-1$$

with integer coefficients $a$ and $b$, where $a$ in particular is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues.

$P(z)$ has no double roots if and only if the system:

$$\begin{cases}P(z)&=&-z^3+az^2+bz-1 &=& 0 & (a)\\P'(z)&=&-3z^2+2az+b &=& 0& (b)\end{cases}$$

has no solution in $z$, a constraint that is equivalent to the impossibility that the resultant of the two polynomials is $0$:

$$\left|\begin{array}{rrrrr}
 -1&   a&   b&  -1&  0\\
0&  -1&   a&   b& -1\\
-3& 2a&   b&   0&  0\\
0&  -3& 2a&   b&  0\\
0&   0&  -3& 2a&  b \end{array}\right|=4(a^3+b^3) + a^2b^2 + 18ab - 27=0.$$

or:

$$(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)+(ab)^2+18(ab)=27$$

which "should" not be possible with integers $a,b$, unless $a=b=1$, or $a=b=-3$, cases that should be ruled out for a specific reason... but honestly, I haven't entered enough into the analysis of (1).